# Expecting to catch an Aggregate Exception

Tags: tpl-dataflow

I am trying to understand exception handling in TPL Dataflow so I can effectively handle errors. In my comment numbered 1. below I am expecting to catch an `AggregateException` but everything just halts and doesn't recover. If I remove the `throw` (2.)  then the `ActionBlock` continues to process but again, the `AggregateException` handler doesn't trigger.

Would anyone be able to help with an explanation to improve my intuition.

Would also welcome any documentation references on the topic.

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var ab = new System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ActionBlock<int>(async a => {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            if (a == 7)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ie.Message);
            throw;  //2. This causes the actionblock to halt, removing allows block to continue
        }

    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await ab.SendAsync(i);
    }
    ab.Complete();

    try
    {
        await ab.Completion;
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ae.Flatten().Message);
        // 1. Expecting to catch here.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. The program completes (doesn't halt). Tested in .NET Core 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `await` unwrapping your Aggregate Exception. When you `await` the completion task the exception is unwrapped and thrown to the general exception catch. But if you don't unwrap the exception then you'd see the exception caught as an aggregate exception like this:

```
try
{
    ab.Completion.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Aggregate Exception");
    // 1. Expecting to catch here.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception Caught");
}
```

It's obviously better to properly `await` the completion but this samples shows you that indeed an `AggregateExcpetion` is caught when it's not unwrapped.